# DNA Motif Enumeration with Try/Except and Loops - Python3

Tags: python, loops, try-catch, bioinformatics, hamming-distance

I've been struggling with a particular bioinformatics problem for the last few days, and I was wondering if somebody could either find the fault in my logic or fault in my code (or both).
The function is supposed to find all k-mers with a Hamming distance of at most d from all of the strings of DNA. 
This is what I'm trying to do:

1. Start with an iteration of all possible k-mers and compare them to each string
2. This implies I need another loop that goes through the strings of DNA as well
3. I make a while loop for `c+k <= len(DNA[0])-1`. `c+k` is my window of size `k`, and I want to find at least one window in each string of DNA where my combo has a Hamming distance from that string equal to or less than an arbitrary `d`. If the Hamming distance meets the criterion, then the while loop breaks,     allowing the next string to be compared. If it doesn't, then the window is changed, and if `c+k==len(DNA[0])-1`, and the Hamming distance still doesn't meet the criterion, I create a name error `int(a)` and the exception kills the `inner_loop`.

However, my function returns nothing except `set()`, which I don't understand.

```
import itertools
def combination(k):
    bases=['A','T','G','C']
    combo=[''.join(p) for p in itertools.product(bases, repeat=k)]
    return combo

def hammingDistance(Pattern, seq):
        if Pattern == seq:
               return 0
        else:
                dist=0
                for i in range(len(seq)):
                        if Pattern[i] != seq[i]:
                                dist += 1
        return dist

def motif_enumeration(k, d, DNA):
    combos = combination(k)
    global pattern
    for combo in combos:
        try:
            inner_loop(k, d, DNA, combo)
        except:
            continue

    return set(pattern)

def inner_loop(k, d, DNA, combo):
    global pattern
    for strings in DNA:
        inner_loop_two(k, d, DNA, combo, strings)


def inner_loop_two(k, d, DNA, combo, strings):
    global pattern
    c=0
    while c+k < len(DNA[0]):
        print(combo, strings[c:c+k], hammingDistance(combo, strings[c:c+k]))
        if d >= hammingDistance(combo, strings[c:c+k]) and strings == DNA[len(DNA)-1]:
            #if we've reached the last string and the condition is met,
            #that means that the combo is suitable for each string of DNA
            pattern += [combo]
        elif d >= hammingDistance(combo, strings[c:c+k]):
            #condition is met for one string, now move onto next
            break
        elif d < hammingDistance(combo, strings[c:c+k]) and c+k == len(DNA[0])-1:
            #Name error causes this inner loop two to crash, thus causing the first inner loop
            #to pass
            int(a)
        elif d < hammingDistance(combo, strings[c:c+k]):
            #change the window to see if the combo is valid later in the string
            c += 1


pattern = []
DNA=['ATTTGGC', 'TGCCTTA', 'CGGTATC', 'GAAAATT']
print(motif_enumeration(3,1,DNA))
print(pattern)
```

I thought that since my second inner loop crashed, this would cause my first inner loop to pass, and then another combo in `motif_enumeration` would be tested, but the first conditional in my `inner_loop_two` never prints anything. I noticed also that when the inner loop crashes and `motif_enumeration` continues, it continues for both the outer and the inner loop. Here's an example of what I mean...

```
AAA ATT 2
AAA TTT 3
AAA TTG 3
AAA TGG 3
AAT ATT 1
AAT TGC 3
AAT GCC 3
AAT CCT 2
AAT CTT 2
AAG ATT 2
AAG TTT 3
AAG TTG 2
AAG TGG 2
AAC ATT 2
AAC TTT 3
AAC TTG 3
AAC TGG 3
ATA ATT 1 etc...
```

My expected output is `pattern=[ATA, ATT, GTT, TTT]`

Comment: Whoever is just hit-and-run downvoting my posts, if you're going to do that, could you at least try and help me out and tell me why my question is stupid? I'm only asking because I put significant time into this problem and sincerely don't know how to fix my code.

Comment: I've just loaded your code and realised I have no idea how to start running this. You never actually call a function to start this off. How do we actually run this?

Comment: @roganjosh I just edited my post. It's at the bottom

Comment: Why are you intentionally causing a NameError, rather than just returning from the function? Also it's a bit tricky tracing the logic of your code, due to the use of that `global pattern`.

Comment: @PM2Ring beat me to it. Currently working on getting rid of `global pattern` and then hoping I can follow the logic after that point :) That's if I can make all the returns I need to follow this through in the first place...

Comment: @PM2Ring I intentionally caused a name error because for some reason, when I returned None if my second last elif statement, my program got stuck in an infinite loop

Comment: I'm not quite clear what your code is trying to do. But I think you want it to return a set of patterns like TTT, since TTT matches the TTT in the first DNA item exactly, the CTT in the 2nd DNA item with a distance of 1, TAT in the next item with a distance of 1, and ATT in the last item with a distance of 1. Is that correct?

Comment: Ok, I understand the expected output in terms of 3 letter combos, what should the output be for your input `DNA=['ATTTGGC', 'TGCCTTA', 'CGGTATC', 'GAAAATT']`?

Comment: @PM2Ring An example of something I want my program to return is ATA because ATA has a distance of at most 1 from all of the strings of DNA.

Comment: Aha, nope, I got it now

Comment: pattern=[ATA, ATT, GTT, TTT] is what I want

Comment: Ok, you should add that expected output into the body of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The core component of the logic is that we want to collect a combo into the pattern set if the combo matches at *any* position on *all* of the target strings. We can use Python's `all` and `any` functions to do this. Those functions work efficiently because they stop testing as soon as the result is decided.

```
import itertools

def combination(k):
    return (''.join(p) for p in itertools.product('ATCG', repeat=k))

def hamming_distance(pattern, seq):
    return sum(c1 != c2 for c1, c2 in zip(pattern, seq))

def window(s, k):
    for i in range(1 + len(s) - k):
        yield s[i:i+k]

def motif_enumeration(k, d, DNA):
    pattern = set()
    for combo in combination(k):
        if all(any(hamming_distance(combo, pat) <= d 
                for pat in window(string, k)) for string in DNA):
            pattern.add(combo)
    return pattern

DNA = ['ATTTGGC', 'TGCCTTA', 'CGGTATC', 'GAAAATT']
print(motif_enumeration(3, 1, DNA))
```

**output**

```
{'GTT', 'ATA', 'TTT', 'ATT'}
```

---

I've made a few other changes to your code. We can calculate the Hamming distance efficiently by passing a generator to the `sum` function. And we can save time & RAM by converting the combo tuples to strings with a generator rather than putting them into a list.

---

The `motif_enumeration` function can be condensed even further into a set comprehension, but I must admit that it is rather dense, and even harder to read than the previous version. It may be slightly more efficient, though.

```
def motif_enumeration(k, d, DNA):
    return {combo for combo in combination(k)
        if all(any(hamming_distance(combo, pat) <= d 
            for pat in window(string, k)) for string in DNA)}
```

---

And here's a slightly more readable version, where I've given `motif_enumeration` a helper function `in_window` to perform the inner test.

```
# Return True if combo is within d in any window of string
def in_window(combo, string, k, d):
    return any(hamming_distance(combo, pat) <= d for pat in window(string, k))

def motif_enumeration(k, d, DNA):
    pattern = set()
    for combo in combination(k):
        if all(in_window(combo, string, k, d) for string in DNA):
            pattern.add(combo)
    return pattern
```

Comment: I understand now. I missed it having to be common to all strings given to the function.

Comment: This is a very elegant answer. If only I knew about any and all before... Thank you

Comment: @DrJessop My pleasure! I've added a slightly more readable version to the end of my answer. Generators / comprehensions can be hard to read at the best of times, and nesting them makes it that much harder. ;)